# laravel-filemanager, Sort by time default

Tags: php, laravel-5, file-management

I need load files order by "time DESC" when the iframe of laravel-filemanager is called.
Is posible? I read the code and see that we cant order by time DESC and the code dont have options to configure a default "sort_type"

https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-filemanager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm change the code in vendor/unisharp/laravel-filemanager/src/traits/LfmHelpers.php
and it's worked

```
   public function sortFilesAndDirectories($arr_items, $sort_type)
    {
        if ($sort_type == 'time') {
            $key_to_sort = 'updated';
        } elseif ($sort_type == 'alphabetic') {
            $key_to_sort = 'name';
        } else {
            $key_to_sort = 'updated';
        }


           return strcmp($a->{$key_to_sort}, $b->{$key_to_sort});
        });

        return $arr_items;
    }
```

with

```
public function sortFilesAndDirectories($arr_items, $sort_type)
    {
        if ($sort_type == 'time') {
            $key_to_sort = 'updated';
        } elseif ($sort_type == 'alphabetic') {
            $key_to_sort = 'name';
        } else {
            $key_to_sort = 'updated';
        }

        uasort($arr_items, function ($a, $b) use ($key_to_sort) {
            if ( $a->$key_to_sort == $a->$key_to_sort )
                return 0;
            else if ( $a->$key_to_sort > $a->$key_to_sort)
                return -1;
            else
                return 1;
        });

        return $arr_items;
    }
```

Comment: These snippets could use spaceship operators.

Answer (score 3):

this is not good idea but it's work for me

i am change the code in vendor/unisharp/laravel-filemanager/public/js/script.js

```js
var sort_type = 'alphabetic';
```

to

```js
var sort_type = 'time';
```

if you want to sort date in desc order. change the code in

vendor/unisharp/laravel-filemanager/src/Controllers/ItemsController.php

```
public function getItems()
{

    $currentPage = self::getCurrentPageFromRequest();

    $perPage = $this->helper->getPaginationPerPage();

    $items = array_merge($this->lfm->folders(), $this->lfm->files());
    return [
        'items' => array_map(function ($item) {
            return $item->fill()->attributes;
        }, array_slice($items, ($currentPage - 1) * $perPage, $perPage)),
        'paginator' => [
            'current_page' => $currentPage,
            'total' => count($items),
            'per_page' => $perPage,
        ],
        'display' => $this->helper->getDisplayMode(),
        'working_dir' => $this->lfm->path('working_dir'),
    ];
}
```

with

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function getItems(Request $request)
{

    $currentPage = self::getCurrentPageFromRequest();

    $perPage = $this->helper->getPaginationPerPage();

    $files = $this->lfm->files();
    if($request->sort_type=='time'){
        $files = array_reverse($files);
    }

    $items = array_merge($this->lfm->folders(), $files);
    return [
        'items' => array_map(function ($item) {
            return $item->fill()->attributes;
        }, array_slice($items, ($currentPage - 1) * $perPage, $perPage)),
        'paginator' => [
            'current_page' => $currentPage,
            'total' => count($items),
            'per_page' => $perPage,
        ],
        'display' => $this->helper->getDisplayMode(),
        'working_dir' => $this->lfm->path('working_dir'),
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

LFM 1.8:

Also, you can use this method, if you don't want to change the LFM Src code.
First use this command to generate views :

`php artisan vendor:publish --tag=lfm_view`

Find this file:

```
ROOT/resources/views/vendor/laravel-filemanager/grid-view.blade.php
```

and change the cod according the follow:

```
  @if((sizeof($files) > 0) || (sizeof($directories) > 0))

  <div class="row">


<!-- -----------------------------------Begin of added block -->

<?php
    $file_temp = [];
    if($files != null){
        foreach ($files as $key => $value) {
            $file_temp[$value['updated']] = $value;
        }
        krsort($file_temp);
        $file_temp1 = [];
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($file_temp as $key => $value) {
            $file_temp1[$i] = $value;
            $i+=1;
        }
        $files = $file_temp1;
    }
?>
<!-- ---------------------------------------End of added block -->


  @foreach($items as $item)
  ....
```

...

As you can see, the `<?php ?>` code block was added.You can use `krsort()` or `ksort()` as you want for **descending** or **ascending**.

Answer (score 0):

In 2.3 I did next steps

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=lfm_view
```

Then you can find file

```
ROOT/resources/views/vendor/laravel-filemanager/grid-view.blade.php
```

And after incuding

```
<script>{!! \File::get(base_path('vendor/unisharp/laravel-filemanager/public/js/script.js')) !!}</script>
```

I added one line of js

```
 sort_type = 'time';
```

But files sorts from the oldest to the newest. Thast's why I redefined routes and ItemsController